# Why String Templates do not pass CI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, continuous-integration

My program works completely, however CI fails it at:

```
export interface FC
{
  offset: `${number}%`;
  ..
}
```

It claims a `TypeScript error: Type expected`. Why?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Interface cannot have values, they are just for the type system.

Comment: Well the purpose was to be a type that defines an object that holds data, but this particular interface wasn't being used at all. I'm now wondering if I should use a 'type' instead of 'interface'

Comment: @T.J.Crowder it should work with TS >=4.1  https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for are [Template Literal Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html). However, it is only available with TypeScript >= 4.1

You should update your TypeScript version in your `package.json`.

After that, it should definitely work:

```
export interface FC
{
  offset: `${number}%`;
}

let valid: FC = {
  offset: '1%'
}

let invalid: FC = {
  offset: '1'
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgMQGEAoAb2LjgnXQGdgYAuOAAwBJSkBXAWwCM0AXwCkLANzFBxYgBsGcAG6YZCACbMicALxxylanQbMA5AEZhxydLnxkSleoKFtuilRr0mcM5cFA)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yes! Also the first time I'm using it :D
Thanks for the edit, I will definitely think about adding a playground link in the future.